# Python implementation for Stop and Wait Algorithm

Tags: python, for-loop, implementation, wait

I am trying to implement a stop and wait algorithm. i have a problem in implementing the timeout at the sender. While waiting for an ACK from reciever, i am using the recvfrom() function. However this makes the program idle, and i can't follow the timeout to re transmit.

**here is my code:**

```
import socket

import time

mysocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


while True:


   ACK= " "

    userIn=raw_input()
    if not userIn : break
    mysocket.sendto(userIn, ('127.0.0.01', 88))     
    ACK, address = mysocket.recvfrom(1024)    #the prog. is idle waiting for ACK
    future=time.time()+0.5   
    while True:
            if time.time() > future:
                    mysocket.sendto(userIn, ('127.0.0.01', 88))
                    future=time.time()+0.5
            if (ACK!=" "):
                    print ACK
                    break 
mysocket.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sockets block by default.  Use the socket funcitons setblocking() or settimeout() to control this behavior.

if you want to do your own timing.

```
mysocket.setblocking(0)
ACK, address = mysocket.recvfrom(1024)
```

but I would do something like

```
import socket

mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
mysocket.settimeout(0.5)
dest = ('127.0.0.01', 88)

user_input = raw_input()

while user_input:
    mysocket.sendto(user_input, dest)     
    acknowledged = False
    # spam dest until they acknowledge me (sounds like my kids)
    while not acknowledged:
        try:
            ACK, address = mysocket.recvfrom(1024)
            acknowledged = True
        except socket.timeout:
            mysocket.sendto(user_input, dest)
    print ACK
    user_input = raw_input()

mysocket.close()
```

Comment: You really should not use an empty except clause, unless you are rethrowing the exception. You know it will be a socket.timeout, so why not catch just that one?

Comment: @drxzcl just added that ;)

Comment: `while not acknowledged` instead of `while acknowledged` or did I miss something?

Comment: @mtahmed hmm, wonder why no one noticed that for over 8 months, lol, fixed, thanks.

Comment: Why did you set the timeout outside the while loop, but not right after sending the user_input to the destination?

Comment: @KaleJoe the socket shouldn't need to have timeout set everytime you send something.  Just once is fine